# jQuery enable dropdown based on first option

Tags: php, jquery

I've tried to find answer to my problem through google, but had little success. I'm new to **jQuery** so the answer is probably simple.

I have 2 dropdown fields on my form, both being populated from the database.

```
<select name="fld_1" id="fld_1">
    ..set of options from DB..
</select>
<select disabled name="fld_2" id="fld_2">
    Please select value from field above
</select>
```

2nd field is disabled until user selects a value from the first field. That value is passed to a php file which runs a database check, and returns a set of options. All of this is controlled by **jQuery**:

```
$(function() {
    $('#fld_1').change(function() {
        $('#fld_2').load('fetch.php?ccID=' + $('#fld_1').val());
    });
});
```

**PHP** output if results found:

```
<option value="aaa">
    aaa - descr
</option>
<option value="bbb">
    bbb - descr
</option> ....
```

**PHP** output is no results found:

```
<option value="0">
    No accounts found for this cost center
</option>
```

What I want to achieve is this: 
`if the value of the first option is 0 keep the dropdown disabled, if anything else remove the disable attribute`.

Thank for the help

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#fld_1').change(function(){
    $('#fld_2').prop('disabled', $(this).val() === 0);
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/J7DK9/1/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).